# For loop inside other for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a String array like this:

```
one
twoo
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
```

For each 3 elements, I want to create a new object setting fields of that object to the elements. For example:

```
one
twoo
three
```

would be used like:

```
obj.setOne("one");
obj.setTwoo("twoo");
obj.setThree("three");
```

I think that I have to use one for inside other but I don´t know how.

I have tried like this but bad result:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> myobjects;
MyClass my_object = new MyClass();

for (int z = 0; z < myarray.size(); z++) {
    for (z = 0; z < (z + 3) && z < myarray.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            mipartido.setAttributeOne(datos.get(i));
        }
        else if (i == 1) {
            mipartido.setAttributteTwoo(datos.get(i));
        }
        else if (i == 2) {
            mipartido.setAttributeThree(datos.get(i));
        }
        myobjects.add(mipartido);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do `z < z + 3` as that will always be the case. Besides, this won't compile, you haven't declared  `i`. Finally, it's "two" not "twoo".

Comment: You need to use a different loop variable (different from `z`) in your inner loop.

Comment: Get your counter variables straight. You are using `z` in booth loops and additionally `i` in the inner loop, which you haven't declared anywhere.

Comment: Let me guess:  is the compilation failure "variable `myobjects` might not have been initialized"?

Comment: I think you might be looking for the [modulus operator](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html), but I'm not really sure. For each input do you want three method calls or do you want alternating method calls?

Comment: Do you intend to get all permutations of three elements shown?  So with nine elements, you'll have 9 x 8 x 7 = 504 lines of output?

Comment: Btw "two" only has one "o"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to only use one loop iterated by 3 if you're sure that myarray will always have a size equals to x*3.

```
            MyClass mipartido;
            for  (z=0; z< myarray.size(); z+=3){
```

Then on the beginning of each iteration, you have to recreate a new mipartido object ( but declare it before the loop)

```
                mipartido = new MyClass();
                mipartido.setAttributeOne(datos.get(i));
                mipartido.setAttributteTwoo(datos.get(i+1));
                mipartido.setAttributeThree(datos.get(i+2));
                myobjects.add(mipartido);
        }
```

By using this, your ArrayList should be filled with 3 mipartido objects, all diferents.
But remember that your "myarray" size must be a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to use one loop but iterate by 3:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myarray.size() - 2; i+=3) {
    mipartido.setAttributeOne(myarray.get(i));
    mipartido.setAttributeTwoo(myarray.get(i+1));
    mipartido.setAttributeThree(myarray.get(i+2));
}
```

<sub>FYI: The English word for the number 2 is spelled "two".</sub>

Comment: @david I changed it to `i < size() - 2`... 1 less char :)

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Bohemain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27829961/1944335), but I wanted to suggest an alternative using the [Modulus operator](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html) (that I think OP was going for in the original post).

```
for (int i = 0; i < myarray.size(); i++) {
    switch (i % 3) {
        case 0:
            mipartido.setAttributeOne(myarray.get(i));
        case 1:
            mipartido.setAttributeTwo(myarray.get(i));
        case 2:
            mipartido.setAttributeThree(myarray.get(i));
    }
}
```

You could do it this way such that your for loop still increments by one each time, but you alternate the method call. As explained [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-mod.html), the operator simply gets the remainder.

So as you increment, the switch statement will work like this:

`0 % 3 = 0`, `1 % 3 = 1`, `2 % 3 = 2`, `3 % 3 = 0`, etc